Listview.builder() horizontal list is not showing up on screen
i am implementing a horizontal listview inside a column which has parent singlechildscrollview
i have extraced widget as CategoriesView from that column
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class CategoriesView extends StatefulWidget {
  const CategoriesView({
    super.key,
    required this.mQWidth,
    required this.mQHeight,
  });

  final double mQWidth;
  final double mQHeight;

  @override
  State<CategoriesView> createState() => _CategoriesViewState();
}

class _CategoriesViewState extends State<CategoriesView> {
  List<CategoryModel> categories = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    getCategories();
    super.initState();
  }

      
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //fetch categories from API

    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 14),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            // Categories Scrolling Widget
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 2,
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: widget.mQWidth / 25),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      const Text(
                        'Category',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 15,
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Text(
                          'View All >',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 13,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 100,
                  width: widget.mQWidth,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: categories.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      var cat = categories[index];
                      return Card(
                        surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        elevation: 5,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Image.asset(
                              catimgURL + cat.categoryURL,
                              width: 40,
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 5,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "abcd${cat.categoryName}",
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 9),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

i tried using Expanded, SizedBox widget,
used shrinkWrap ture and scrollDirection to axis.horizontal. nothing works.
if i remove Listview.Bulder code works as usual. i think the problem is ListView.
help is appriciated.

Does the console show any errors?

Please check your List data because it's can fetch null data so it's can't be display in listview.

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
The relevant error-causing widget was:

Try below code hope its help to you. just replace your data with my data/widgets.
Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 14),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              // Categories Scrolling Widget
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 2,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        const Text(
                          'Category',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 15,
                          ),
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: const Text(
                            'View All >',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 13,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 100,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: 10,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Card(
                          surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          elevation: 5,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Image.network(
                                'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTD6czyExeLPPzSlfAyP32nKxy_S-lPEIowBlnUXV1NPA&s',
                                width: 40,
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 5,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "abcd",
                                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 9),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),

Result Screen - 
